# Theano inner product 3d matrix

Tags: python, linear-algebra, logistic-regression, theano

thanks for reading this.

I'm trying to implement a multi-label logistic regression using theano:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
rng = numpy.random

examples = 5
features = 10
labels = 2
D = (rng.randn(examples, labels, features), rng.randint(size=(labels, examples), low=0, high=2))
training_steps = 10000

# Declare Theano symbolic variables
x = T.matrix("x")
y = T.vector("y")
w = theano.shared(rng.randn(1 , labels ,features), name="w")
b = theano.shared(0., name="b")
print "Initial model:"
print w.get_value(), b.get_value()

# Construct Theano expression graph
p_1 = 1 / (1 + T.exp(-T.dot(x, w) - b))   # Probability that target = 1
prediction = p_1 > 0.5                    # The prediction thresholded
xent = -y * T.log(p_1) - (1-y) * T.log(1-p_1) # Cross-entropy loss function
cost = xent.mean() + 0.01 * (w ** 2).sum()# The cost to minimize
gw, gb = T.grad(cost, [w, b])             # Compute the gradient of the cost
                                          # (we shall return to this in a
                                          # following section of this tutorial)

# Compile
train = theano.function(
          inputs=[x,y],
          outputs=[prediction, xent],
          updates=((w, w - 0.1 * gw), (b, b - 0.1 * gb)),
          name='train')
predict = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=prediction , name='predict')

# Train
for i in range(training_steps):
    pred, err = train(D[0], D[1])

print "Final model:"
print w.get_value(), b.get_value()
print "target values for D:", D[1]
print "prediction on D:", predict(D[0])
```

but -T.dot(x, w) product fails with this error:

TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "train"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 2, got 3 with shape (5, 10, 2).')

x has shape (5, 2, 10) And W (1, 2, 10). I would expect the dot product to have shape (5,2).

My questions are:
Is there anyway to do this inner product?
Do you think there is a better way to achieve a multi-label logistic regression?

thanks!

---- EDIT -----

So here is an implementation of what I would like to do using numpy.

```
x = rng.randn(examples,labels,features)
w = rng.randn (labels,features)
dot = numpy.zeros((examples,labels))
for example in range(examples):
    for label in range(labels):
        dot[example,label] = x[example,label,:].dot(w[label,:])
print dot
```

output:

```
[[-1.70321498  2.51088139]
 [-5.73608956  0.1066286 ]
 [ 2.31334531  3.31892284]
 [ 1.56301872 -0.56150922]
 [-1.98815855 -2.98866706]]
```

But I don't know how to do this symbolically using Theano.

Comment: isn't dot product supposed to return a single number? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product May be you need T.tensordot?

Comment: I guess this might be a generalization of a dot product, in the single-label logistic regression example in theano.
They multiply train_x (examples, features) with the Weights (features) and obtain the dot product (examples)
(5, 10) dot product (10,) = (5,)

After applying the other element-wise operations to come up with the sigmod function they end up with predictions vector with shape (examples,), this is one prediction per example. But because I want to do multi-label, I want a matrix of size ( examples, number of labels) as a prediction

Comment: That seems to me the standard [matrix x vector product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Square_matrix_and_column_vector).

Comment: Right, but instead of matrix x vector, is matrix3d x matrix2d

Comment: Last time I checked, multi-label prediction was achieved by training for every label separately and then looking at which predictor gave the best confidence. Simultaneous multi-label prediction would be less reliable (or you'd need a lot more data for it).

Comment: But I have a 3d volume composed of 32 * 32 * 32 voxels, and I want to learn map to another volume of the same shape, and it's very important the correlation between voxels. I don't think it will work if I trained this label separately.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of fighting this seems to produce the right results:

I had an error which was having the input as rng.randn(examples,features,labels) instead of rng.randn(examples,features). This means, that besides having more labels, the inputs should be the same size.

And the way of computing the dot product the right way was using theano.scan method like:
results, updates = theano.scan(lambda label: T.dot(x, w[label,:]) - b[label], sequences=T.arange(labels))

thanks everybody for their help!

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
rng = np.random

examples = 5
features = 10
labels = 2
D = (rng.randn(examples,features), rng.randint(size=(labels, examples), low=0, high=2))
training_steps = 10000

# Declare Theano symbolic variables
x = T.matrix("x")
y = T.matrix("y")
w = theano.shared(rng.randn(labels ,features), name="w")
b = theano.shared(np.zeros(labels), name="b")
print "Initial model:"
print w.get_value(), b.get_value()

results, updates = theano.scan(lambda label: T.dot(x, w[label,:]) - b[label], sequences=T.arange(labels))

# Construct Theano expression graph
p_1 = 1 / (1 + T.exp(- results))   # Probability that target = 1
prediction = p_1 > .5                         # The prediction thresholded
xent = -y * T.log(p_1) - (1-y) * T.log(1-p_1) # Cross-entropy loss function
cost = xent.mean() + 0.01 * (w ** 2).sum()# The cost to minimize
gw, gb = T.grad(cost, [w, b])             # Compute the gradient of the cost
                                          # (we shall return to this in a
                                          # following section of this tutorial)

# Compile
train = theano.function(
          inputs=[x,y],
          outputs=[prediction, xent],
          updates=((w, w - 0.1 * gw), (b, b - 0.1 * gb)),
          name='train')
predict = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=prediction , name='predict')

# Train
for i in range(training_steps):
    pred, err = train(D[0], D[1])

print "Final model:"
print w.get_value(), b.get_value()
print "target values for D:", D[1]
print "prediction on D:", predict(D[0])
```